# javascript sort by index and then random?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash, shuffle

I'm using lodash to sortBy index, but among the items with the same index the sorting always comes out to be the same. How do I make sure that the ordering is random if the index are identical?

This is what I have currently:

```
    chosen = _.sortBy(chosen, function(v) {
      return v.index;
    });
```

Comment: well round is not random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vanillJS/ES6 one-liner:

```js
var arr = [{index:5,v:1},{index:3,v:3},{index:3,v:6},{index:1,v:3},{index:3,v:7}]
arr = arr.sort((i1,i2)=>i1.index==i2.index?Math.random()-0.5:i1.index-i2.index)
console.log(arr)
```

EDIT: not-one-liner

```js
var arr = [{index:5,v:1},{index:3,v:3},{index:3,v:6},{index:1,v:3},{index:3,v:7}]
arr = arr.sort(function(i1,i2){
  if (i1.index == i2.index) return Math.random()-0.5;
  else return i1.index-i2.index;
})
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Can you make it not 1 line? It's a bit hard to understand. Thanks.